# Create services out of manifest.yml using cloudfoundry/IBM Bluemix

Tags: node.js, cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, paas

a cloudfounry manifest.yml is a quite powerful way to express the deployment model of an application. That would be really great is if services could also be created as specified in the manifest.yml.

Please consider the following manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name:  MQL.sample.node.backend
  disk: 1024M
  command: node app.js
  path: mqlight_sample_backend_node
  memory: 256M
  instances: 2
  no-route: true
  services:
  - MQLight-sampleservice
- name:  MQL.sample.node.frontend
  disk: 1024M
  command: node app.js
  path: mqlight_sample_frontend_node
  memory: 512M
  host: mqlightsample-node-${random-word}
  services:
  - MQLight-sampleservice
```

This file describes 3 instances of 2 application, all bound to MQLight-sampleservice but this service has to exist before.

I can easily create this service using the cloudfoudry command line tool

> cf create-service MQLight-sampleservice MQLight

But I'd like to have everything in one file, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible with the current cloud foundry cli v6. There is a work item open for this feature: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/892938/stories/65262468

Meanwhile, I recommend creating a script:

createServiceAndPush.sh

```
cf cs mysql 100 mymysqldb
cf push
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if is possible during `cf push` but you can create the services during a deploy using the **deploy to Bluemix** button. That will use a git repository and deploy an app in bluemix creating the services you specified in the `manifest.yml`.

In the `manifest.yml` file you need to specify the service you need before specifying the `applications`.

```
---
declared-services:
  personality-insights-service-standard:
    label: personality_insights
    plan: standard

applications:
- name: personality-insights-nodejs
  command: node app.js
  path: .
  memory: 256M
  services:
  - personality-insights-service-standard
```

See the **deploy to bluemix** documentation [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/deployingapps.html#deploy_button).

Comment: Hi, I've tried this right now, but it doesn't seem to work, I get the same error, using the button or the plain command line: Could not find service MQLight-sampleservice to bind to six-space-manifest-romeokienzler-2139 https://bluemix.net/deploy?repository=https://hub.jazz.net/git/romeokienzler/six_space_manifest

Comment: Here it is https://hub.jazz.net/project/romeokienzler/six_space_manifest/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/git/romeokienzler%252Fsix_space_manifest/contents/master/manifest.yml

Comment: Plase use: `label: mqlight` and
`plan: standard`

Comment: I've done so: ---
declared-services:
  MQLight-sampleservice:
    label: mqlight
    plan: standard , but not working either...

Comment: do you have the pipeline output